# What is the correct way to wire up an input field in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following component in a Redux app for recipes, which currently only has a name right now, for simplicity sake.

```
class RecipeEditor extends Component {

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        this.props.updateRecipe(this.props.recipe, { name: this.refs._name.value })
    }

    render = () => {
        if (!this.props.recipe) {
            return <div />
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" ref="_name" value={this.props.recipe.name} />
                    <input type="submit" value="save" />
                </form>
            </div>)
    }

    static propTypes = {
        recipe: React.PropTypes.shape({
            name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
        })
    }
}
```

This gives me an editor with a textbox that can't be edited. There's a warning in the console as well:

> Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form
>   field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only
>   field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise,
>   set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of
>   `RecipeEditor`.

That makes sense, but I don't want an `onChange` event, I'll use `ref` to get the values on submit. It's not a readonly field obviously, so I try changing it to have a defaultValue.

```
<input type="text" ref="_name" defaultValue={this.props.recipe.name} />
```

This gets closer to the behavior I'm looking for, but now this only sets the recipe when the control is mounted and it no longer updates when a new recipe is chosen.

Is the solution having a handler on every input field that sets state, and then in submit, take all the state and update the recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an input element with the `value`attribute set, it becomes a "controlled" component. See this page for a more detailed explanation:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Long story short, that means that on every render you are setting the value attribute to the value from the props, which will stay the same unless you also update the value in your redux store).

When the input is "uncontrolled" instead (value attribute not explicitly set), its internal state (the value string) is handled implicitly by the browser.

If for some reason you prefer to keep the state locally and you don't want to dispatch a redux action every time the value changes with onChange, you can still manage the state yourself using React component state and dispatch the action on submit:

```
class RecipeEditor extends Component {

    state = {
        recipeName: ''
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        this.props.updateRecipe(this.props.recipe, { name: this.state.recipeName })
    }

    handleNameChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ recipeName: e.target.value })
    }

    render = () => {
        if (!this.props.recipe) {
            return <div />
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" ref="_name" value={this.state.recipeName} onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="save" />
                </form>
            </div>)
    }

    static propTypes = {
        recipe: React.PropTypes.shape({
            name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
        })
    }
}
```

In this example, whenever the input value changes you store the current value in the state. Calling `setState` triggers a new render, and in this case it will set the value to the updated one.

Finally, note you don't have to use `onChange` if you never need to set the input value to something specific. In this case, you can remove the `value` attribute and just use `refs`. That means though that if somewhere else in your code you change the value stored in Redux state, you won't see the change reflected in your input. As you've seen, you still can set the initial value to something specific using `intitalValue`, it just won't be in sync with your redux store. 
However this is not going to work well if for example you want to reuse the same form to edit an existing recipe you have in your store.

Comment: This is right inline with what I expected... yet hoped it wasn't true. It just seems like a lot of overhead for a form that might have several fields.

Comment: See my last edit. You don't really have to use `value` and `onChange`, but you lose the ability to control the data in your form through  Redux. Sometimes that is ok though, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As React already mentioned in the console, you have to provide an "onChange" listener to make that field editable.

The reason behind that is the value property of the input field which you provided

```
{this.props.recipe.name}
```

This value doesn't changes when you type in the input field.
And since this doesn't changes, you don't see the new value in your input field. (Which makes you feel that it is non editable.)

Another thing to note here is that the "recipe.name" should be transferred to the state of your component so that you can set a new state inside "onChange" listener.

see the usage of "setState" function.